Using hunspell in emacs on Windows 10
OK I am at my wit's end on this.  I have found various incantations on the internet for this, but nothing works so far.  I am running emacs 29.2, the native windows build, on Windows 10.  I want to spell check with hunspell.  I decided to use msys2 to build it.  I installed msys2, cloned hunspell from its git repo, and built it.  The exe is C:\msys64\mingw64\bin\hunspell.  "hunspell -D" lists C:\Hunspell as the 2nd dir (after .) where it looks for dictionaries.  I downloaded en_US.{aff, dic} from LibreOffice website to C:\Hunspell.  I added to my .emacs file:
(setq ispell-program-name "c:/msys64/mingw64/bin/hunspell")

At this point, if I try spell checking a buffer, I get the error
Hunspell error (is $LANG unset?): Can't open affix or dictionary files for dictionary named "default".

Some incantations will let me get beyond this and run a spell check, but every single word is marked as an error.
So - please - what do I do?  The pain of getting a spellchecker working on emacs is a major annoyance.  I opened my LaTeX document in TeXWorks (comes with MikTeX) and spellcheck just works out of the box.  Come on emacs......

Don't despair.  I faced the same thing for hours today.  There's a bug in Hunspell v 1.7 which got fixed in v1.7.2
After you extract 1.7.2+ and put it in any directory (like .emacs.d), you'll still need to add Myrr's code into .emacs to 'hardcode' this path. Or you can fiddle with trying to find emacs' automatic search paths in Windows.
For completeness, you'll also need to download dictionaries (see bottom of page), then add that path to Myrr's code.  I also downloaded English words list which I found in this post.
I tested and reduced Myrr's code down to
(setenv "LANG" "en_US.UTF-8")
(setenv "DICPATH" "C:\\path\\AppData\\emacs\\dictionary\\")
(setq-default ispell-program-name "C:\\path\\AppData\\emacs\\Hunspell\\bin\\hunspell.exe")
(setq-default ispell-complete-word-dict "C:\\path\\AppData\\emacs\\dictionary\\english-words.txt")
(global-set-key (kbd "C-/") 'ispell-word)
(global-set-key (kbd "C-M-/") 'ispell-region)


Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

In particular, can you describe the bug fix? Or at the very least, provide a link to the pull request that fixed it?

NickD, does my edit answer your questions? BTW, why?

Try this
(use-package ispell
  :init
  (setenv "DICTIONARY" "en_US")
  (setenv "DICPATH" "C:\\Path\\to\\folder\\with\\dictionary")
  :if (eq system-type 'windows-nt)
  :custom ((ispell-program-name "c:/msys64/mingw64/bin/hunspell.exe")
           (ispell-local-dictionary "en_US")
           (ispell-local-dictionary-alist
            '(("en_US" "[[:alpha:]]" "[^[:alpha:]]" "[']" nil ("-d" "en_US") nil utf-8)))))

